# Touchpad is not working

Tags: touchpad, acer

I bought a new acer E5-574g-50XN laptop with linpus linux. I removed linpus and installed ubuntu. But the touchpad is not working. I googled tried many things but couldn't fix it.

```
uname - r gives 4.2.0-23-generic  
xinput --list shows "SYN1B81:01 06CB:7406 UNKNOWN   id=12 [slave pointer (2 )]
```

dmesg shows `i2c-hid i2c-SYN1B81:01 :failed to retrieve report from device.`

I also tried settings `synclient TouchpapOff=0` but it automatically gets to `TouchpadOff=2`.

When I blacklisted i2c-hid touchpad stopped working completely.
I am a student and I wanted to learn about linux but I am really frustrated right now. And also when I switch off the laptop and leave it for some time then use it, touchpad works for a little time and then starts lagging heavily. It never stops working but lags so much that it is unusable.

Comment: Sorry i could not paste complete output because my laptop is almost unusable and i don't know much about shortcuts of ubuntu. Please help me!!

Comment: Did you have windows installed on this laptop with the same problems?  If Win works without any problems and you want to use Ubuntu, you can install it using virtual machine  (VM) e.g.: VMware Player or Virtualbox...

Comment: I have not tried windows yet

Comment: @markkirby OP says they installed Ubuntu.

Comment: I know this is probably not an issue, but for the users that look in the future; Possible answer in another thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/763763/touchpad-under-16-04-not-working Check that out, hopefully it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just solved it by changing touchpad from advanced to basic in main tab of bios settings.

Comment: Does it work simultaneously with an external mouse?

Comment: Same here. What does advanced do? What will we miss?

Comment: this will cause two finger scrolling and other features to be disabled if you boot in to windows

Comment: Awesome. Man is the Acer BIOS a pile of crap.