# Touchpad under 16.04 not working

Tags: touchpad, 16.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and just recently installed the Version 16.04 
My Touchpad is not working at all and it seems as if it is not detected. 
The USB Mouse however is working perfect.
I'd like to use the Touchpad though.

Is there a way to get it working?

I'm using a MEDION akoya E5218 notebook.

I did not disable it. I tried Fn+F6.

Comment: Maybe you disabled it. Try FN+F6

Comment: in settings menu click on mouse and touch pad then choose "tap to click" option

Comment: Only command worked for me 

    sudo modprobe -r psmouse
    sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps

Comment: @Motte001 this is what happened to me.  In my case, it is Fn+F7, but in general it depends on the keyboard layout.  Luckily mine is drawn onto my keyboard.

Comment: First check if Touch-pad isn't disable from mouse & Touch-pad setting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you type

```
less /proc/bus/input/devices
```

do you see a touchpad anywhere in that list? If not, then there is no support for your touchpad in the kernel and you are pretty much out of luck, at least for now. If your touchpad is detected then the problem is elsewhere. Typing

```
xinput
```

will show if the X server has detected your touchpad. If your touchpad is in that list it may be possible to modify the X config to make it work

Comment: Can you explain How to change the xinput value? My touchpad is listed there.

Comment: @DavidFoerster It is not my question. I faced a similar problem. So I commented on the accepted answer to get more details. The answer said we can modify x config value to fix things. I was asking him some detailed steps or reference links. Again, **It is not my question**.

Comment: @KolappanNathan: Sorry, my oversight. Never mind then.

Comment: Touchpad is not listed.. Is there a driver I can install?

Answer (score 16):

My touchpad sometimes gets stuck (especially on a fresh boot).

In my case, reloading the driver works. First I unload the module from the kernel (using `rmmod` (**r**e**m**ove **mod**ule)) and then reinsert it (using `modprobe`):

```
sudo rmmod i2c_hid
sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

Answer (score 9):

Follow these instructions to fix the issue,

modify `grub` file,

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

replace

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"
```

Save the file and then update grub using,

`sudo update-grub` command.
and then restart your OS,

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works for me and also it fixes another issue I have with the CAPS Lock that was always on :)

Answer (score 6):

1. Edit GRUB

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   In the open window edit line

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   It should look this way

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp"
   ```

   Save file and run

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
2. Prevent `i2c_hid` from loading

   ```
   echo "blacklist i2c_hid" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/i2c-hid.conf
   sudo depmod -a
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   echo "synaptics_i2c" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
   ```
3. Reboot.

What it does is, it removes the synaptics hid drivers from the blacklist and allows them to be loaded at the initialization of the RAM file system, allowing your touch pad to work at boot

Comment: Don't use `sudo` for graphical applications; use `gksudo` instead!

Comment: @FatemehKarimi Glad it worked for you :)

Comment: This worked for me on HP Elitebook 1050. Thank you!

Comment: It also worked for Acer Aspire 3 Ryzen5 AMD processor.Thanks:)

Comment: But scroll option with two fingers is disabled and lot available in tochpad option which ws available before this.

Answer (score 1):

For my **Akoya** laptop this worked fine:

#### 1. Try the following:

- reboot to the grub menu and type **e** (hope it is right, --> you have to  edit your command line)
- in the line starting with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
  insert the following kernel properties:

  ```
    "i8042.reset i8042.nomux=1 i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
  ```
- if your touchpad is now working, go to point 2.

#### 2. Permanent Grub modification

- Make a backup of your grub file:

  ```
    sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup
  ```
- Edit your grub file:

  ```
    sudo nano /etc/default/grub
  ```
- Now add the following paramters into the line starting with  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` :

  ```
    "i8042.reset i8042.nomux=1 i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
  ```
- Save the file
- Update your grub

  ```
    sudo update-grub
  ```
- Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to upgrade your kernel. I find that Ubuntu kernels below 4.5 don't find my Elantech touchpad by default.

You can upgrade to a newer version, like 4.5 using the instructions found here:

[How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

Comment: I checked this, nothing worked.