# Extreme cursor delay with Acer Aspire E15 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, acer, cursor

Occasionally my laptop will enter a state where the cursor starts lagging so bad that it's unusable.  Oddly during this state, everything other than the cursor is still completely responsive.  I.e. anything that only involves the keyboard (opening a terminal, typing, etc) is unaffected.  Once it enters this state, on successive reboots and shutdowns it re-enters this state within seconds.  However, if I shutdown and leave it alone for a few minutes, it does not immediately re-enter this state.

Based on search results for "acer aspire ubuntu freeze" I have tried setting the intel_idle_max_cstate field in grub to 0, 1, and 2, but this did not seem to help.  To be clear - I am not experiencing any crashes, the system is completely responsive except for the cursor is delayed to the point where it would take several seconds to go from one edge of the screen to the other.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is really specific to Acer models. I have a DELL XPS 13, which worked wonderfully with 14.04, but the motions of the bluetooth mouse (Logitech Ultrathin Touch Mouse) mouse cursor are now extremely slow, actually delayed, on 16.04. When you stop moving the mouse cursor continues to move for a while. Like it were on drugs. No problem with the built-in touchpad or the radio attached mouse (rapoo keyboard + mouse).

Comment: Thanks for sharing; I'm still having the same issues with the touchpad,  but with a wireless usb mouse I'm having no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the exact same issue on my own Aspire E-15 (running Ubuntu 16.04). In your BIOS, change the "Touchpad" setting from "Advanced" to "Basic". For reference, xinput identifies the touchpad as a "ELAN0501:00 04F3:3019 Touchpad" when the BIOS option is set to "Advanced", and "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" when set to "Basic".

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this extreme cursor delay on my new Acer Aspire F5-573G as well when my machine is computing a heavy load.

I am hopeful this solution may work - see the last post here:
[Touchpad under 16.04 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763763/touchpad-under-16-04-not-working)

Edit GRUB

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

In the open window edit line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

It should look this way

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp"
```

Save file and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Prevent i2c_hid from loading:

```
echo "blacklist i2c_hid" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/i2c-hid.conf
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u
echo "synaptics_i2c" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Reboot.