# Dell touchpad not working

Tags: touchpad, dell

I am using ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop dell inspiron 5577 gaming.My touchpad has not been working since i installed ubuntu though the touchpad works fine in the pre installed windows 10.I have tried the solution from [Touchpad under 16.04 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763763/touchpad-under-16-04-not-working?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and it doesn't even detect my touchpad,i have tried many solutions i don't know what to do now.It even has few other problems like the battery indicator is not showing and the laptop doesn't even shutdown properly.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact laptop with the exact same problem(among others) with ubuntu 16.04.

I'm not entirely sure if this is what fixed it but all I did after countless non working solutions offered by others on the internet was:

- Upgrade the kernel to the very latest out at the time. *I used UKUU to make it easy.*
- Rebooted(it automatically selects the newer kernel at boot)

**and voila! My touchpad was working again.**

Also, check to make sure in the Hardware Drivers section if you have any proprietary drivers that need to be installed.

That generally solves a few issues.