# Touchpad stopped working in my Dell inspiron 3000 series and there is no enable disable option in touchpad setting

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, dell

Suddenly my touchpad stopped working, and when went to check if touchpad setting is disabled in touchpad setting, I found no enable/disable button there.

Also,I can see USB optical mouse in that list but not touchpad :

[image]

No enable disable button/option :

[image]

`dmesg` when touchpad isn't working

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KJWmkx3YRm/

Comment: probably driver error, do you check `dmesg`?

Comment: No I don't know how to do that. Would you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: just open the terminal (you can do it with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`), and just type `dmesg`; copy and paste the result here (`Ctrl`+`C` didn't work to copy on the terminal)

Comment: Okay, I have done that and I can see something like a logfiles. But I can't understand them.

Comment: I have pasted here, thanks in advance. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KJWmkx3YRm/

Comment: Is your touchpad working when you do the `dmesg` command?

Comment: No, sir it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the 2nd and 3rd answer of here [Touchpad under 16.04 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763763/touchpad-under-16-04-not-working).
Then I did 
i. sudo apt-get update
ii. sudo apt-get install

After that I went to sleep for 9 hours(kept laptop shutdown for 9 hours).
And it started working again.[working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLJ55.png)