# Ubuntu ASUS touchpad driver (16.10 / 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, asus, 16.10

I have an N580GD ASUS laptop runing Ubuntu 16.10 but could not turn on the touchpad some how

```
xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G Mouse                                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
...
```

what should I do to turn it on?

later: installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but have the same problem.

later2: I tried to load the "Try Ubuntu..." from the usb flash I previously installed my OS and there my touchpad works fine. so i've compared their grub files and was surprised that they are identical...

Comment: Possible off-topic question.  Ubuntu 16.10 was released in 2016.October (hence the 16.10) with a supported life on 9 months, which is well since over. It upgraded to 17.04 (2017-April release, now EOL also), then to 17.10 (2017-October also EOL) , then to 18.04 LTS.  Questions about EOL releases are off-topic unless your question is about moving to a supported release (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).  I suggest installing a supported release, and using a LTS or long-term-support release if you don't like upgrading often

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but have the same problem. I get the same answer with my " xinput --list " request...

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/a/1050135/790920

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work either.

Comment: I tried to load the "Try Ubuntu..." from the usb flash I previously installed my OS and there my touchpad works fine. so i've compared their grub files and was surprised that they are identical...