# Cursor not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cursor

When I had Ubuntu 12.04 this command worked

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Now that I have upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 this command doesn't work. I even tried various ways, but they didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "cursor is not working", exactly? What device(s) are involved here?

Comment: Means cursor not appearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
sudo rmmod i2c_hid
sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

Comment: It asked for my password , then it was success . But didn't work .........

Comment: try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/763763/touchpad-under-16-04-not-working

Comment: this worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Try the below if not working means tell me I will tell another solution

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false`

Comment: Command was successful but didn't produce any result

Comment: Does mouse pointer appearing or not ?

Comment: `modprobe -r psmouse` 
      `modprobe psmouse`